# How to integrate Qmetry and Karate framework

Tags: qaf

I have UI built on top of Qmetry framework. Just wanted to check if I want to integrate Karate framework. Is it possible to integrate Karate framework with Qmetry framework ?

Comment: Do you know qaf has ws support library with request call repository, XML/json response validations, UI-api orchestration and special support for openapi?

Comment: Yes I am aware. But there is a specific ask from one of our client to integrate Karate framework. Is it possible to do ?

Comment: Is this question for QMetry or qaf? QMetry is commercial test management tool while qaf (qmetry automation framework) is open source framework for functional test automation.

Answer (score 1):

If your client's use case is to upload Karate test results to QMetry Test Management, it's possible. Karate has the support for Cucumber (BDD) and generally the automation test results files could be generated in .json format. QMetry Test Management (Standalone) and QMetry Test Management for Jira (QTM4J) both products have inbuilt support for Cucumber automation file uploads, the test cases, test executions and execution results shall be automatically imported to the QMetry products. You can refer the following resources for uploading the test results to QMetry.

For QMetry Test Management (Standalone)

- [Upload Automation Test Results to QMetry using Automation API](https://qmetrysupport.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/QPro/pages/377094257/Import+Automation+Results+through+REST+API).
- [Upload Cucumber Framework Test Results to QMetry](https://qmetrysupport.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/QPro/pages/619315297/Test+using+Cucumber)

For QMetry Test Management for Jira

- [Upload Automation Test Results to QTM4J using Automation API](https://qmetrysupport.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/QTM4J/pages/1000866944/Import+Results+using+Rest+API)
- [Upload Cucumber Framework Test Results to QTM4J](https://qmetrysupport.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/QTM4J/pages/1000899168/Test+using+Cucumber)

Note - Mostly, the .json results shall be directly uploaded to QMetry. Incase if the result file format do not match the supported format of QMetry, you can write a translator that can convert your results into a QMetry supported format and upload it OR you can take help from QMetry Support - qtmprofessional@qmetrysupport.atlassian.net to create a translator for you. Based on my experience the QMetry support team is very responsive and resourceful.